# how basic server in php works

Tags: php

I want to ask a conceptual question: how a server written in php works?

Actually I want to know when I write a simple php code to get some information from a client, how does the whole process happen?

In java I have to start server first. Server listens to the port. When any client knocks then connection creates. Is it similar to php? Before running client application do I have to run my php code or server will do that for me? I am using localhost.

Comment: Server in PHP? It's been done, nanoserv

Answer (score 0):

see this article: http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_daemons_in_php/

> Before running client application do I
>   have to run my php code or server will
>   do that for me.

This depends on your server architecture, you can use something like inet.d which invokes your script only if there is access on that port, or you have the standalone version, where you start the php from console und it waits for connections.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it similar to php ?

Yes.

> Before running client application do I have to run my php code or server will do that for me.I am using localhost.

If you are writing a server in PHP then your PHP code **is** the server.